# Can I add permission to new profiles after re-installing a managed package

Tags: managed-package, permissions, package, package-install

I have a managed package which I have installed in Salesforce. Now I have some new profiles created. From what I understand, if I un-install the managed package and re-install it from all profiles, including the new profiles, will that provide the permissions?

If not, is there any Salesforce documentation, which clearly states this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you re-install your managed package you will be able to choose again what profiles can have access to this package.

Comment: Is there any documentation of Salesforce which states this? That permissions can be provided with reinstallation? @OlehMykytyn

Comment: @OlehMykytyn, you can simply reinstall in one of your sandbox and assign the profiles or permissions

Comment: You should be able to change access to package in Profile - Edit profile-  Custom App Settings: - Enable app and save. Also, you can check ISV Guide for more details https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf